# Negativity for a diagonal reduced density matrix

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Suppose one has a tripartite system A,B,C with density matrix $\rho$ , and with reduced density matrix $\rho_{BC}=\text{Tr}_A\ \rho$. Suppose  $\rho_{BC}$ is a diagonal matrix.

As the partial transpose of a diagonal matrix corresponds to the same matrix, and since all the matrix elements are positive, the negativity 
    $\mathcal{N}(\rho_{BC})=\sum_i \frac{\vert \lambda_i\vert-\lambda_i}{2}$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of the partial transpose 
    $\rho_{BC}^{T_B}$
is zero.

How it is possible to say whether the state is entangled or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A state with a diagonal density matrix is always separable (=not entangled): If
$$
\rho= \sum p_{ij} |ij\rangle\langle ij|\ ,
$$
then a separable decomposition is given by
$$
\rho = \sum p_{ij} \sigma_{ij}^A\otimes\sigma_{ij}^B\ ,
$$
with $\sigma_{ij}^A=|i\rangle\langle i|$ and $\sigma_{ij}^B=|j\rangle\langle j|$.